# Rails 4 and gem sunspot cannot order correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

Im getting this error:

```
Sunspot::UnrecognizedFieldError in SitesController#products
No field configured for Product with name 'created_at'
```

here is my model **Product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    searchable do 
      text :name
      text :description
      text :specification

      string  :name
    end
end
```

and here is a mehod in my controller:

```
def list_all_products
    @search = Product.search do
      fulltext params[:search]
      order_by :created_at, :desc
    end

    @products = @search.results
  end
```

the *name* field in my table products is a *string*. I defined in searchable products both for text and string. Why I still getting an error like this? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

just add `time :created_at` in your model

```
 class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   searchable do 
     text :name
     text :description
     text :specification
     time :created_at

     string  :name
   end
 end
```

Comment: its not raise an error now, but the product not order accordingly to desc at created_at :(

Comment: what db are you using?

Comment: so I thought! I also have the same issue with postgre, when there is a searching, scope does not work properly! in development sqlite3 and all work fine

Comment: I see, so its an issue then, I must not use sunspot with postgresql then :(

Comment: this issue will always if you want to use search in postgresql, scope results will be not correct